# One-to-many relationships in datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, one-to-many

There is a nice explanation of 1-to-many relationships in datastore [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling.html) by Rafe Kaplan. I tried to adapt that to a simpler case of `User` and `Venue`. So user can go to many restaurants; and I want to print the user email and the restaurants the user went to:

```
class User(db.Model):
    userEmail = db.StringProperty()

class Venue(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User,
                                   collection_name="venues")
    venue = db.StringProperty()

class OneToMany(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        scott = User(userEmail="scott@example.com")
        scott.put()
        Venue(user=scott,
                     venue="club1").put()
        Venue(user=scott,
                    venue="club2").put()

        for v in scott.venues:
            self.response.out.write(v.venue)
```

This prints `"club1 club2"`

But I want to associate `"scott@example.com"` with the places he went to; so I want to print something like: `"scott@example.com: club1, club2"`

Trying

```
for v in scott.venues:
    self.response.out.write(userEmail)
    self.response.out.write(v.venue)
```

gives the error:

```
self.response.out.write(userEmail)
NameError: global name 'userEmail' is not defined
```

What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks!

**EDIT2** (re: answer by vonPetrushev)

This seems to work:

```
query = User.all()
    query.filter("userEmail =", "scott@example.com")
    results=query.fetch(1)
    scott=results[0]
    self.response.out.write("%s went to:" % scott.userEmail)
    for venue in scott.venues:
        self.response.out.write(venue.venue)
```

Displays:

`scott@example.com went to:club1club22`

**EDIT** (re: answer by vonPetrushev)

I am a little bit confused.

So I want to write a query like this

```
query = User.all()
query.filter("userEmail =", "scott@example.com")
```

and display all the venues associated with this user.

It is not clear how `User` and `Venue` is connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userEmail` is not a defined name in the scope of the `for` loop. What you need is:

```
for v in scott.venues:
    self.response.out.write(scott.userEmail)
    self.response.out.write(v.venue)
```

**EDIT**: Concerning your edit - if your goal is to make a joined query - you can't, not with the google app datastore. However, you can grab the user like this:

```
query = User.all()
query.filter("userEmail =", "scott@example.com")
results=query.fetch(1)
scott=results[0]
```

and then get the venues like `scott.venues`. The relation is defined in the line with `db.ReferenceProperty`, which defines what is `someuser.venues` and what is `somevenue.user`.

Comment: Thanks this works and prints: `scott@example.com club1 scott@example.com club22` I added an `EDIT` because I don't understand how to query for the user and get all its venues.