# How to access items in a model with ReferenceProperty?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, referenceproperty

This is a follow up on [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294562/how-to-query-datastore-when-using-referenceproperty).

I set up the models with ReferenceProperty:

```
class User(db.Model):
    userEmail = db.StringProperty()

class Comment(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name="comments")
    comment = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

class Venue(db.Model):
    user = db.ReferenceProperty(User, collection_name="venues")
    venue = db.StringProperty()
```

In datastore I have this entry under User:

```
Entity Kind: User
Entity Key: ag1oZWxsby0xLXdvcmxkcgoLEgRVc2VyGBUM
ID: 21
userEmail: az@example.com
```

And under Venue:

```
Entity Kind: Venue
Entity Key: ag1oZWxsby0xLXdvcmxkcgsLEgVWZW51ZRhVDA
ID: 85
venue (string): 5 star venue
user (Key): ag1oZWxsby0xLXdvcmxkcgoLEgRVc2VyGBUM
User: id=21
```

I am trying to display the item in `hw.py` like this

```
query = User.all()
    results = query.fetch(10)
    self.response.out.write("<html><body><ol>")
    for result in results:
        self.response.out.write("<li>")
        self.response.out.write(result.userEmail)
        self.response.out.write(result.venues)
        self.response.out.write("</li>")
    self.response.out.write("</ol></body></html>")
```

This line works:

```
        self.response.out.write(result.userEmail)
```

But this line does not work:

```
        self.response.out.write(result.venues)
```

But as [per vonPetrushev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294562/how-to-query-datastore-when-using-referenceproperty/4294641#4294641) `result.venues` should grab the `venue` associated with this `userEmail`.

Sorry if this is confusing: I am just trying to access the tables linked to the `userEmail` with `ReferenceProperty`. The linked tables are `Venue` and `Comment`. How do I access an item in `Venue` or in `Comment`? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`venues` is actually a [query](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html) object.  So you'll need to fetch or iterate over it.

Try replacing the `self.response.out.write(result.venues)` line with a loop:

```
query = User.all()
users = query.fetch(10)
self.response.out.write("<html><body><ol>")
for user in users:
    self.response.out.write("<li>")
    self.response.out.write(user.userEmail)
    self.response.out.write("<ul>")
    # Iterate over the venues
    for venue in user.venues:
        self.response.out.write("<li>%s</li>" % venue.venue)
    self.response.out.write("</ul></li>")
self.response.out.write("</ol></body></html>")
```

However, this will not scale very well.  If there are 10 users, it will run 11 queries!  Make sure you are using [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats.html) to look for performance issues like these.  Try to minimize the number of RPC calls you make.

A better solution might be to denormalize and store the user's email on the Venue kind.  That way you will only need one query to print the venue information and users email.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Considering the performance issues you mentioned I decided to add `latestVenue` property to `User` and now I display it as `result.latestVenue`. But I also save it under `Venue` as `ReferenceProperty` for later use. I assume this is better. Thanks again for your help.